# how to test subdomain redirect with rspec and FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am learning rspec and trying to test my Account controller on create. After a user creates an account (i.e. chooses a name and a subdomain), he's redirected to a login page on his new subdomain.

My test returns `NoMethodError: undefined method 'subdomain' for #<Hash:0x00000107888c88>`

My account Factory is setup to generate a subdomain, so I don't see a problem with my logic. Is is just a syntax issue ?

```
accounts_controller.rb
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_session_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain, mp: 'signup' ) }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end

/specs/controlles/accounts_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe AccountsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      before :each do
        @account = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:account).merge( owner_attributes: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:owner) )
      end

      it "redirects to the account subdomain login page" do
        expect(post :create, account: @account).to redirect_to new_user_session_url(:subdomain => @account.subdomain)
      end
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not save the new account in the database"
      it "re-renders the :new template"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like your factory is at fault. Looking at the error, I'm guessing that `@account` is a hash instead of an object so when tried `@account.subdomain` it produced the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, `@account` is a hash of account attributes

```
@account = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:account).merge( owner_attributes: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:owner) )
```

The above line returns a hash which you are passing as parameter while making the request

you should probably be doing `account[:subdomain]`

```
expect(post :create, account: @account).to redirect_to new_user_session_url(:subdomain => @account[:subdomain])
```